# Why won't my Python code to find all divisors of a number print them out?

Tags: python-3.x

I feel like I have the right code to determine the divisors for a requested number, but my code won't actually print out the numbers.

I tried writing this with a for loop and a while loop but the issue seems to be in printing out the numbers.

```
n = int(input("Let's find the divisor, type in a number: "))
x = 1
print("The divisors for this number are: ")

def divisor(n):
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(x)
```

I expected the divisors for the given number to be printed.
Instead, they were not printed. Any ideas on why?

Comment: You need to call the function with `divisor(n)` afterwards.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to call the function, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `divisor(n)` function after it's been defined. So you can call the print command after `divisor()` has been defined, or put the initial code in a function and call that function at the end of the script so it goes over all the code before executing anything.
I also added a try/except statement to confirm the input is an int().

```
def main():
    in_num = input("Let's find the divisor, please type in a number: ")
    # Get input number from user and assign to variable "in_num"
    valid_num = confirm_int_input(in_num)
    # Call the confirm_int_input() function to confirm the input is an int() with the "in_num" variable.

    even_numbers = divisor(valid_num)
    # Call the divisor() function to get all the evenly divisible numbers and assign it to the variable "even_numbers"
    print('The evenly divisible numbers of "', valid_num, '" are: ', even_numbers, sep='')
    # Print "even_numbers" with an explanation.

def confirm_int_input(test_int):
    try:
        valid_int = int(test_int)
        # Validate input can be a type int()
        return valid_int
    except ValueError:
        # Input can't be converted to valid int() so print an error.
        print('Error, "', test_int, '" is not a valid integer.', sep='')
        quit()
        # Stop the script.

def divisor(num):
    even_divisors = ''
    for divide_by in range(1, num + 1):
    # For loop to check all possible even divisor combinations.
        if num % divide_by == 0:
        # if num is exactly divisible by 0 then:
            even_divisors += '\n' + str(divide_by)
            # str() of all evenly divisible numbers (new line before each one).
            # This could also be substituted for a list or something like that.
    return even_divisors
    # return the evenly divisible numbers str() to the main function.

main()
# Call the main function.
```

Comment: Ah -- can't believe I forgot to call it. Thank you!